# Cyclic Inference while using RxJava Async

Tags: android, lambda, java-8, rx-java, rx-android

I am using the following as an Async task using RxJava in Android.

```
Async.start(new Func0<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() {
                return exampleFunction();
            }
        }).subscribe();

String exampleFunction() {
    return "Test";
}
```

I am trying to update this code using Java 8.

However, it is reporting **"Cyclic Inference"** in the above code. Not sure, what I am missing.

Any pointers to the problem.

```
Async.start(s -> exampleFunction()).subscribe();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you pass must have no parameter, so replace "s" by "()":

```
Async.start(() -> exampleFunction())
```

Or even better:

```
Async.start(this::exampleFunction)
```

Comment: WoW! that's real quick... Thanks alot! 
Any reference to quick tutorial where I can deep dive into Java 8 notations?

Comment: No. A good way to learn lambda is to use the autocompletion / refactoring features within IntelliJ / Android Studio. Write your code as Java 7, the IDE will suggest to transorm it automatically to Java 8.

Comment: @Maverick Here's one for lambda expressions https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html. And they are a lot of other resources on the web if needed.

Comment: @clemp6r My Android Studio reports that the expression could be converted but it does not do auto-completion. Are there any specific configurations I need to enable? or it works by default? I am using Android Studio 1.1.0.

Comment: The auto-completion dialog should appear when you type "Async.start(" and then CTRL+space. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, the auto-completion dialog appears but it does not complete the code in the lambda style. Reference to auto complete image.
http://imgur.com/pBSuArn

Comment: Thanks @clemp6r, I did Android Studio 1.2 beta and it is really helpful.